# Center Conditional Icon Set Icons over Data

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2016

I the only answer I've been able to find on the web is that you can't do it. I know that is not true at least with Excel 2016 because Microsoft did it them selves in the College Move Checklist template.

[image]

The problem is I can't seem to find the settings to get it to work. I've been through all the rules and formatting but can't find it. I was able to copy and paste it to work in some of the items I needed it for but I needed to make it from scratch for others.

Does anyone know how to acheive this?

[image]

Comment: In conditional formatting rule, set [x] Show Icon Only and set the cell to be center aligned.

Comment: Thanks Axel, I had tried that before but it didn't work. After your post I went back and tried it again. I found that it you have already applied center alignment to the column before you save that change to the rule it will not work. You must remove the alignment formatting on the column and then re-center. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the conditional format and check the "Show Icon Only" checkbox.  This will remove the data from visibility and show only the icon, which will then adhere to the alignment you specify.

*This answer from the comment by Axel Richter*